# PyCharm cannot find routines in Numpy sub-modules

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm, but have been using Python for a while. I'm using Python 3.3.2 with Numpy. I've just started to use PyCharm, and right now the editor is complaining about the following. If I use the following code for example,

```
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
```

then the `normal` part is highlighted, and when I move the mouse over it it says "Cannot reference `normal` in `__init__.py`. Does anyone know why it cannot reference `normal()`? I can assure you that this function does exist in the sub-module `np.random`.

Comment: Knowing nothing about pycharm I can only guess that it doesn't like the fact that the random module is a very thin wrapper on top of a C code, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/random

Comment: WOW, how on earth did you know that!? I wouldn't even have thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing about pycharm I can only guess that it doesn't like the fact that the random module is a very thin wrapper on top of [a C code](http://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/random).